# 'get' method in Rails controller tests throwing "no route matches" for controller scoped by module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec, rspec2

I can't seem to work around the 'get' method in my rspec controller specs for my scoped routes.

I'm scoping the routes for my 'visitor' controllers so that they are within the 'visitor' module namespace, but are at the root of the routing.  So 'mysite.com/foo' goes to the Visitor::FooController.

config/routes.rb

```
scope :module => 'visitor' do
  resources :inquiries
end
```

spec/controllers/visitor/inquiries_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Visitor::InquiriesController do
  describe 'GET new' do
    it 'should render template visitor/inquiries/new' do
      get :new
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/visitor/inquiries_controller.rb

```
class Visitor::InquiriesController < Visitor::BaseController
  def new
  end
end
```

When I run the spec I get the following error.

```
No route matches {:controller=>"visitor/inquiries", :action=>"new"}
```

I tried adding some additional parameters for get (e.g. :url => 'inquiries/new', :controller => 'inquiries') but I can't seem to get around this issue.  Hitting 'inquiries/new' with my browser works fine and shows that my routes are working as expected.

I'm new to rspec so there may be some fundamental issue I'm not understanding here.  Otherwise I'm looking for a way to push past this issues so I can test these 'visitor' controllers.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this isolated? Do other routes work?

Comment: I just tried a controller spec for an 'admin' controller and the "get :new" worked fine.  The difference with these 'admin' controllers is that the routes are scoped by 'admin' (e.g. 'admin/accounts').

Comment: Maybe `Visitor::InquiriesController` should descend from `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Perhaps I should have taken out the inheritance from Visitor::BaseController for the question as it shouldn't have any effect.  Just to be sure though I just tried inheriting directly from the ApplicationController and received the same error message.  Also the admin controller that I tested for stef uses a similar inheritance scheme (inherits from Admin::BaseController).

Comment: I duplicated this configuration and did not see an error. You say it works outside of RSpec, which is puzzling. Does Visitor::BaseController do anything special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed when I restarted my computer the next day.  There seemed to be some sort of issue with Spork that was causing the problem.  I'm not sure if this question can be removed, but it probably doesn't provide a lot of value to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to your config/routes.rb
uncomment follow line: match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
Now it should works

Comment: Don't do this. It exposes all controller actions to GET requests, which aren't subject to CSRF protections.